# How to make the carat visible in IE when the background color is dark gray?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a login page that can be themed by the user with any background color, image, or both. The username/password inputs will have transparent backgrounds to allow the page background to bleed through. In one customer case, the background color was chosen as #867d7d. They claim the carat (they called it the "cursor") is not visible while focused into the fields. The carat actually is there blinking like normal, but its color is so close to the background color that you can't see it.

Is there any way to make the carat visible in this case?

Edit: This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, the issue is only happening in Internet Explorer.

Here is a live demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y80ftqg/)

```
<style>
body { background-color: #867d7d; }
input { color: white; background-color: transparent; width: 100%; }
</style>
<input placeholder="The caret is nearly invisible in IE">
```

Comment: you must be meaning : IE, FF, Chrome, ....

Answer (score 1):

This seems that IE respect the windows theming, instead config-able from its browser level.

You can change yoru windows theming here: "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization", and pick some extreme color you will see the carat color got changed.

I am hope IE would have carat color CSS styles.